# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android-studio

Here is my fooddetail activity codes

```
public class FoodDetail extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView food_name,food_price,food_description;
ImageView food_image;
CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
FloatingActionButton btnCart;
ElegantNumberButton numberButton;

String foodId="";

FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference food;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_detail);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    food = database.getReference("Food");

    numberButton = (ElegantNumberButton)findViewById(R.id.number_button);
    btnCart = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.btnCart);

    food_name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.food_name);
    food_description = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.food_description);
    food_price = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.food_price);
    food_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_food);

    collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)findViewById(R.id.collapsing);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.ExpandedAppBar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.CollapsedAppBar);

    if (getIntent() != null)
        foodId = getIntent().getStringExtra("FoodId");
    if(!foodId.isEmpty())
    {
        getDetailFood(foodId);
    }
}

private void getDetailFood(String foodId)
{
    food.child(foodId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Food food = dataSnapshot.getValue(Food.class);

            Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(food.getImage()).into(food_image);

            collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(food.getName());
            food_price.setText(food.getPrice());
            food_name.setText(food.getName());
            food_description.setText(food.getDescription());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

and here is my xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.order.m.jersonsordering.FoodDetail">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/collapsing"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="#0e0d0e">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:id="@+id/img_food"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:title="Food Name">


            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnCart"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:useCompatPadding="true"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/food_name"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:padding="12dp"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:text="Food Name"
                        android:textSize="21sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/layout_price"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="1dp"
                            android:layout_weight="9"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/food_price"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:padding="12dp"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:text="1,000PHP"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:id="@+id/number_button"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                        app:textSize="8sp"
                        app:backGroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        app:textColor="#000000"
                        app:initialNumber="1"
                        app:finalNumber="20">

                    </com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton>

                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/food_description"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:text="Description"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="14sp"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I dont know what is causing the error and i cant resolve it I tried to rebuild and clean the project

I also tried searching for similar error but none is showing 
the app keeps on closing and then thats the error(attached photo)

pls help me thank you :)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have included design library `implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'` in your application level build.gradle.

Then replace:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton 
...
...
android:backgroundTint

/>
```

with

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton 
...
...
app:backgroundTint
/>
```